# A probability distribution in n dimensional space which its projection on any line is a uniform distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions

Does there exist, for any natural $n$, a probability distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose projection on any line is a uniform distribution?

Comment: A uniform distribution along a (whole) line would have infinite integral.

Comment: I meant a uniform distribution on a sub-interval of that line.

Comment: A uniform distribution in some cube?

Comment: This has the property only for lines parallel to the edges of the cube.

Comment: If your initial distribution is a uniform distribution along a line $L_0$, then the projection on any line which is not orthogonal to $L_0$ is uniform on a subinterval of that line.

Comment: @Salavati: do you know the answer for the two-dimensional case? A positive answer in three dimensions would imply a positive answer in two dimensions by projecting the measure onto the plane. So I think that it will help to consider the two-dimensional case first.

Comment: The answer for the two dimension is positive. If one choose a uniform point on the surface of a three sphere and then project it on the x-y plane, the resulting distribution has the property.

Comment: I have answered my own question for 3 dimensions in the previous comment! The uniform distribution on the surface of 3-sphere.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6964/ for $n=2$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No if $n\geq 4$. By translating we may assume that the mean is $0$, and by scaling we may assume that the variance-covariance matrix is the scalar matrix $(1/3)I$. Then all projections have mean $0$ and variance $1/3$, hence are uniform in the interval $[-1,1]$.

So if we take a random projection, the value will also be uniform in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Let $\mathbf x$ be a random variable along such a distribution. Clearly $|\mathbf x|\leq 1$ with probability $1$. The probability that the absolute value of the projection of $\mathbf x$ in a random direction is at least $1-\epsilon$ is an increasing function of $|\mathbf x|$, so it is at most the probability that the projection of a unit vector in a random direction has length at least $1-\epsilon$. This is the same as the proportional of the unit $n-1$-sphere that is in a spherical cap of depth $\epsilon$, which is $\approx \epsilon^{(n-1)/2}$.

On the other hand, because the distribution is uniform, the probability that the absolute value of the projection of $\mathbf x$ in a random direction is at least $1-\epsilon$ must be $\epsilon$. So we have $\epsilon  \leq \epsilon^{(n-1)/2}$, and thus $n\leq 3$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I'm saying that by scaling we may assume the variance-covariance matrix is the identity matrix, or for conveneince $(1/3)I$.

Comment: Thanks, nice argument! I think it actually also works for $n=3$ because the spherical cap $z\ge 1-\epsilon$ has prob $\sim\epsilon/2$ wrt surface measure, if I got it right.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Technically you have to consider both spherical caps, giving another factor of $2$. I ignore the constant term if the $n \geq 4$ case because it's irrelevant.

Comment: Right. So for $n=3$ the argument shows that any such measure is supported by the sphere.

Comment: Using Will's observation on mean and covariance, one can also assume the measure to be symmetric under rotations without loss of generality. The reason is that having projection uniform on $[-1,1]$ is a property which is invariant under taking mixtures of measures. Hence if some measure has this property, then so does its convolution with a random rotation (chosen from the Haar measure on $O(n)$).

Comment: Hence we work wlog with a measure of the form $f(r)\, d\Omega\, dr$, where $d\Omega$ is the volume element of the sphere (and $f$ may be distributional), i.e. an integral over the uniform measures on spheres for varying radius of the sphere. For these measures, it should be a straightforward calculation to determine whether there exists some $f$ for which $f(r) \, d\Omega\, dr$ satisfies the OP's requirement.

Comment: @ChristianRemling But doesn't the uniform measure on the sphere work?

Comment: Addendum to my comments: now I understand that Will achieves something equivalent by considering a random projection. Clever!

Comment: @WillSawin: It does, as is actually obvious from the formula $dz\, d\varphi$ for the surface area measure. Somehow it seemed intuitively "clear" to me that there is more area near the equator than near the poles.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2$ there is a solution with a *density* w.r.t. Lebesgue measure : $c\ dx\ dy/\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ on a circular disc of radius $R$. So you have three possibilities :

1°) Anthony Quas's uniform distribution on subintervals of straight lines ($n\geq 2$);

2°) uniform distribution on spheres in 3-dimensional subspaces of $n$-dimensional space ($n\geq 3$);

3°) the one above on discs in planes ($n\geq 2$).

Plus their images (push forward) by affine maps, but probably no other, if I have to guess.